# Why 'sencha app build' won't build last changes?

Tags: extjs, cmd, build, production

I have been trying to build a Sencha application for production with the last made changes using `sencha app build` by running CMD from the following folder: *C:\xampp\htdocs\myApp\web>*, however after running the command for more than 10 times, the changes don't appear in: *localhost/myApp/web/build/production/myApp/index.html*

Does anyone know why would this happen? Thank you.

Comment: You have to open your sencha cmd from `myApp` folder.

Comment: Turned out to be a Chrome's caching problem, the build was fine.